# Why is virtualenv not finding editable packages previously installed via pip -e?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Starting a few days ago I'm having to reinstall my editable packages for every new virtualenv session. I have the impression that this didn't happen in a not so distant past.

Every time I switch to a virtualenv the packages previously installed (in the same virtualenv, of course) via pip -e aren't found. Any idea of what can be happening? Is this a expected behavior?

I'm using virtualenv 13.0.3 and it's using pip 7.1.2 internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had two packages with the same name defined in their setup.py files. Every time I installed one the other was uninstalled.

To make things worse, even after I changed one of the package's name the problem persisted. This was because the previous egg dir, generated by setuptools (I guess), was still there.